# Avoiding formatting of DOORS object text using DXL

Tags: ibm-doors

I am writing DXL script in which few object text has borders(like one complete row of table is copied).

I have to emphasize the "shall" word in **shall**.
But using findPlainText() method, it changes the formatting of object text which have borders.
Initially the objects before scripts run is:

[image]

After running the script to make "shall" word Bold, i wrote DXL script:

```
void Change_Shall(Object o, string objText)
{


    int off=0
    int len=0
    string StartUpperText = ""
    string FontText = ""
    string StartText = ""
    string FindText = ""

    bool IsChanged = false
    string OriginalObjText = objText
    string UpperFontObjText = upper(objText)
    while (findPlainText(UpperFontObjText, "SHALL", off, len, true, false))
    {
        StartUpperText = UpperFontObjText[0:off-1]
        UpperFontObjText = UpperFontObjText[off+len:]

        FindText = OriginalObjText[off:off+len-1] 
        StartText = OriginalObjText[0:off-1]
        OriginalObjText = OriginalObjText[off+len:]
        if(FontText == "")
          FontText = StartText "{\\b " FindText "}"
        else
          FontText = FontText StartText "{\\b " FindText "}" 

    //print FindText "\t\t" UpperFontObjText "\n"
        IsChanged = true

        off = 0
        len = 0
    }


    if(IsChanged == true)
       o."Object Text" = richText FontText OriginalObjText 

}
```

The object text with border after this script runs get changes like

[image]

How can formatting of object text with borders be avoided and border is preserved in the object text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're getting `"Object Text"` from `Object o`, but my guess is you're using `o."Object Text" ""` to cast it  as a string. Is that right?
If so, then that is stripping all the rich text (including your borders) before you do anything to it. Try using `string objText = richTextWithOle o."Object Text"`, or `string objText = richText o."Object Text"`, and then try removing the unnecessary parameter to your function `string objText`, as a reference to this already comes along with `Object o`

I'm assuming based on how your table looks that it is a RichText table, in which case I believe your code will still work, it's just that I suspect you're starting with a string stripped of richText and adding richtext to it. Sometimes Word OLE objects with tables can look like that too, in which case you'd have to use COM to manipulate the OLE.

Hope this helps.